# How to check needed power supply for my PC?

Tags: hardware, ups, system-info

I want to buy UPS, but don't know parameters. How i can check my hardware for it?

Comment: Power requirements cannot be accurately measured just by software alone or opinion. You need to add to the question what hardware are you going to run (all specs and parts count, include models, versions, etc).

Comment: @Bruno Pereira, i thought, there some apps exist for check all of it...

Answer (score 3):

If you want a real accurate measurement of power consumption, you need to measure actual current draw from the power supply with a tool like a WattsUp, while the system is under maximum load.

Optionally, just look at your power supply's wattage (e.g. 600 watts), add the wattage of all the stuff you also want on the UPS (screen, speakers, and so on) and buy a UPS that can handle slightly more than that. UPS are normally rated in VA (Volt Amperes) rather than watts but for this purpose they should be close enough. For instance if the total wattage from your appliances is  850 watts, a 1000-VA UPS should have you covered.

Comment: Close Enough (TM) means you should add 20-40% overhead.